# Chatting and file sharing using C# in Asp.Net Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, chat, file-transfer

NET Web-forms based application in c#. I need to add a module in the application which allows chatting between logged in users and users can share files during chatting, like Skype. Meanwhile I have to keep a PERMANENT RECORD of each and every word of conversation and files transferred during the session, on my server. I have a bit idea about the implementation of module to achieve the desired result, but I am sure that is not a good practice. Here is my idea:

Chatting:
While users are chatting, create a data-table which will contain the sender id, receiver id, and message contents. When ever user presses send button or hit Enter, a new row would be inserted in the data-table with both IDs and message contents and then the data-table will be bound to a div etc. to show updated messages to both users. At  the end, on an event (like window close etc) data-table will be converted to the XML and the XML file will be stored permanently either on hard disk or in database.

File-transfer:
During chatting whenever user press enter/send button we will check the message contents, if the message being sent is a file (with some extension) then upload the file on server and provide a download link to the receiver.

I hope you got my point.

Problem:

1) I want to share files asynchronously i.e. transfer to the receiver and save on the server at the same time. Is it possible?

2) How to tell one user that the other user is typing?

Is there any better way to implement this module? What sort of knowledge should I have to properly comprehend and implement the module?

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: How many users do you expect to have simultaneously?

Comment: What is your time to market?

Comment: Are you willing to make use of commercially available API's and public networks?

Comment: mind marking my answer as correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For web-based real-time chat the current open source standard bearer seems to be [SignalR](http://signalr.net/).

There are quite a few discussions here on SO about that product and those should help move you in the right direction.

As far as storage is concerned, that will depend upon the infrastructure you have available and the costs you are willing to incur to build the system.

You might look into using [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com) for message delivery and if you set that up appropriately, you can attach queue listeners that will also perform logging of chats as needed.  (There are well documented .NET/C# clients already available for RabbitMQ.) You may also want to check out the [Wikipedia page for RabbitMQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RabbitMQ%E2%80%8E).

File transfer would probably be best done through uploading of the file to the web-server and temporary storage there with a link to the file to be downloaded by the other chat client.  That causes the server to increase its bandwidth requirements though.

You might also look into running your own [XMPP server](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/) and using a web interface through SignalR to interface into the [XMPP server](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/).  It might leverage the most functionality for easing time to market.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [SignalR](http://signalr.net/)?